# R Aggregate with rle function

Tags: r

struggling with this one :
Sample data :

```
    foo <- structure(c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2",
"2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "C", "C", "C", NA, NA, NA, NA, "C",
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "C",
"C", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C",
"C", "C", "C", NA, NA, NA, NA, "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C",
"C", "C", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "C", "C", "C", NA,
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "C", "C", "C", NA, NA,
NA, NA, NA, "C", "C", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "C", "C", "C", NA,
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "C", "C", NA, NA,
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "C", "C", "C", "C",
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C",
"C", NA, NA, "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", NA, "C", "C", "C", "C",
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C",
"C", "C", NA, NA, "C", "C", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
NA, NA), .Dim = c(15L, 13L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("weeks",
"vv", "rv", "ja", "aa", "bv", "aj", "vb", "rj", "rr", "vr", "bb",
"jr")))
```

How to group theses datas by weeks and apply rle function ? Expected output would be :

```
out <- structure(c("weeks", "1", "2", "vv", "1", "1", "rv", "0", "1",
"ja", "1", "1", "aa", "1", "1", "bv", "1", "0", "aj", "1", "1",
"vb", "1", "0", "rj", "1", "0", "rr", "1", "1", "vr", "2", "2",
"bb", "1", "1", "jr", "1", "0"), .Dim = c(3L, 13L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, NULL))
```

Tried so far :

```
test <- aggregate(foo, by=data.frame(foo[,1]), function(x,na.rm=T) rle(as.numeric(x))$values)
```

Gives me a list (as expected with rle) which I could then compute and try to get the expected output. But I'm sure there is a cleaner way to accomplish that... Any ideas ?

Thanks for looking !

Comment: do you really have a matrix input and want a matrix output? How are you determining the output values?  I don't see how the 11h column (`vr`) in `out` isn't both 2 (or both 1...)  You're looking for the number of runs in each week?

Comment: Yes, matrix as input and as output. The output values are the numbers of runs in each weeks. Yes vr in out should be both 2, question edited.

Comment: Almost... Great idea. Didn't know I could use condition within rle. If I understand your 
code, you "omit" NA values by specifying lengths > 1 ? 
Is that right ? The problem is that I need to sum 
those runs that are of length 1 too...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently a bunch of ways to process the rle output; here's another.

```
d <- data.frame(foo)
aggregate(!is.na(d[,-1]), d[,1,drop=FALSE], function(x) sum(rle(x)$values))
#   weeks vv rv ja aa bv aj vb rj rr vr bb jr
# 1     1  1  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  1  1
# 2     2  1  1  1  1  0  1  0  0  1  2  1  0
```

Comment: You can avoid first converting to a `data.frame` as follows: `aggregate(!is.na(foo[, -1]), list(weeks = foo[, 1, drop=FALSE]), function(x) sum(rle(x)$values))`. +1

Comment: Works great on my actual data set. The idea was to !is.na. Why the drop=FALSE ?

Comment: `drop=FALSE` keeps it as a data frame (which is a kind of list) so you don't need to wrap the second eargument in a call to `list`, as @mrdwab suggests.  Either way works just fine, it's just personal preference as to which to use.

Answer (score 4):

I wound up with something very similar... not sure which answer you're looking for:

```
aggregate(list(foo[, -1]), list(weeks = foo[, 1]), 
          function(x) length(na.omit(rle(x)$values)))

  weeks vv rv ja aa bv aj vb rj rr vr bb jr
1     1  1  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  1  1
2     2  1  1  1  1  0  1  0  0  1  2  1  0
```

Comment: +1 I didn't see the OP's updated "out". I think this is what they're looking for. If it is, I'll delete my answer to keep things tidy. By the way, were you able to get this output as is? I have to use `rle(as.character(x))`.

Comment: No, I couldn't get output as is, need as.character

Comment: Oh, I have "options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` in my `.Rprofile`... always forget that its not default!